# PT100 sampling and accuracy

Tags: sensor, temperature

How accurate can I get temperature measurements if I repeatedly sample the data from a PT100 sensor. [Assuming I have a 16 bit converter]?
What are the limits on accuracy and repeatability? Does the accuracy increase as the square root of the number of samples?

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer for all the different sources of error. Precision increases with more samples but not necessarily accuracy due to systematic errors.

Answer (score 1):

Limits include the sensor accuracy (calibration and interchangeability at the temperatures of interest), self-heating of the sensor, coupling of the sensor to the thing you're trying to measure, effect of the sensor on the thing you're trying to measure (heat input or heat loss, for example), instrument calibration and changes in that with time and environmental factors, and noise.

Noise (including quantization noise) is the only one that you can improve by averaging measurements, and not necessarily even that, depending on the type of noise.

Most errors sources are systematic, so you may get really low-noise measurement of a value that is not very accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy of your DAC is a comparison of the actual output of a DAC with the expected output. It is expressed as a percentage of a full-scale, or maximum, output voltage. For example, if a converter has a full-scale output of 10V and the accuracy is ±0.1 %, then the maximum error for any output voltage is (10 V)(0.001) =10 rnV. Ideally, the accuracy should be, at most, ±'/2 of an LSB. For an 16-bit converter, 1 LSB is 1/65536 = 0.000015 (0.0015% of full scale). The accuracy should be approximately ±0.2%.

in wiki they give you therelation between the sample size and accuracy :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination.
"Larger sample sizes generally lead to increased precision when estimating unknown parameters. For example, if we wish to know the proportion of a certain species of fish that is infected with a pathogen, we would generally have a more accurate estimate of this proportion if we sampled and examined 200 rather than 100 fish. Several fundamental facts of mathematical statistics describe this phenomenon, including the law of large numbers and the central limit theorem.

**In some situations, the increase in accuracy for larger sample sizes is minimal, or even non-existent**. This can result from the presence of *systematic errors* or strong dependence in the data, or if the data follow a heavy-tailed distribution."

Comment: Isn't this question about ADCs and not DACs?

Comment: sorry, i mean to say ADC not DAC.